# StackOverflow in AWTEventMulticaster

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

how do you debug the below exception?
there is nothing on the stack that points to client code

```
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,902 - java.lang.StackOverflowError
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,903 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,903 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,906 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,907 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,909 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,911 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,912 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,914 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,916 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,917 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
CERROR 2017-06-28 17:30:03,920 -    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.hierarchyChanged(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: the stack is too long to display your code. can you show your calling to hierarchyChanged?

Comment: I don't call that method directly, it is called indirectly by the Swing mechanisms.